# Panel Notifications in html. it is possible?

Tags: linux, centos6, plesk

I have a Centos 6.5 linux with plesk 11.5.

I want to know if its possible to modify the Panel notifications for HTML layout?

I found that I can modify the template text here:

Server Management -> Tools & Settings -> Panel -> Notifications

I'm not able to find where I can edit the HTML, or if there is a component to do that.

Any idea?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Suggest this idea on https://plesk.uservoice.com/ or vote for related ideas https://plesk.uservoice.com/forums/184549-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3672070-being-able-to-modify-the-subject-in-notification-e

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I'll do it now :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have to disappoint you, but it's impossible.